# What is the best starting planet in Race for the Galaxy (base set)

Tags: race-for-the-galaxy

I've seen stats on BGG which include expansion sets but couldn't find stats on just the base set. I would like to know which starting planet has the highest probability of winning, which has the second highest, etc.

Based on experience, I believe Earth's Lost Colony and Alpha Centauri are above average but I'd love to see stats based on thousands of games played (or more) if available.

Comment: check out Keldon's AI and its site - maybe there is some data to be mined there http://keldon.net/rftg/games.cgi

Answer (score 1):

I don't have stats, but the conventional wisdom is that production/consumption strategies are dominant in the base set, so ELC is generally thought of as the best. New Earth vs. Alpha Centauri seem like a toss-up to me for second.

Comment: I saw stats somewhere that showed New Earth having a hard time when expansion sets are included, and that accords with the games I play. But I don't have the stats to prove it. Alpha Centauri and ELC seem to win most often in my games though I don't really new which is better between the two.